# Can I take both armies to battle?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I have two barracks in Clash of Clans. When I go to battle, army of first troop goes to battle. Can I take the army from both barracks, or choose which army will go to battle?

Comment: When you battle, whatever troops are in your Army Camps and in the Clan Castle will be available, as well as any spells. If troops are still training in you barracks, you will have to wait for them to be ready.

Answer (score 3):

When you go to battle, all troops in the Army Camps will go with you, and you can use them.